# Why does TimeZoneInfo.IsValidTime() give unexpected result for DateTimeKind.Local?

Tags: c#, timezone

I am surprised by the behaviour of TimeZoneInfo.IsValidTime() as it doesn't work as I expected with an invalid DateTime set as DateTimeKind.Local

```
[Fact]
public void DateTimeInvalidForTimeZone()
{
    TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");

    var testTimeUnspec = new DateTime(2020, 3, 29, 02, 01, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    var testTimeLocal = new DateTime(2020, 3, 29, 02, 01, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
    var testTimeUtc = new DateTime(2020, 3, 29, 02, 01, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    Assert.False(timeZone.IsInvalidTime(testTimeUtc));     //as anticipated - UTC so cannot be invalid
    Assert.True(timeZone.IsInvalidTime(testTimeUnspec));   //as anticipated - the time is invalid
    Assert.False(timeZone.IsInvalidTime(testTimeLocal));   //unexpected - the time is invalid
}
```

Note: Central European Standard Time transitions to daylight saving on 29 March 2020 at 02:00AM so the time sequence in terms of local time is 01:59:58, 01:59:59, 03:00:00, 03:00:01. Accordingly all local times between 02:00:00 and 02:59:59 are invalid.

The [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isinvalidtime?view=netcore-3.1) explains:

- In the case of a DateTimeKind.Local and TimeZoneInfo that is non-local (i.e. different to the computer's timezone)  **IsValidTime(DateTime)** converts the DateTime to the time of the TimeZoneInfo object and returns false.

This suggests that DateTime objects that are DateTimeKind.Local will be always be valid which is not what I expect or want. Can anyone explain the logic behind Microsoft's implementation? Yet another reason to consider [Nodatime?](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/userguide/rationale)

Comment: You have a local time that is not valid.  What do you expect as a result?  DateTime are stored in the computer (and Net) as a number in UTF.  Then when date is displayed as a string Net applied the timezone setting of the computer as the default format.  When dates are parsed in Net from string to number the default is to take local time and convert to UTF unless the string contains a timezone.

Comment: I expect IsInvalidTime() to return TRUE when passed an invalid date and FALSE when passed a valid date. It doesn't do that in my last test; hence my question. My tests only pass when Assert.False for this last test.

Comment: I guess the New DateTime is converting to UTC.  Once it been converted it is no longer invalid.  Suppose somebody was working a 2:30 when the time transition.  The person forgot to change their watch.  The Net library just converts the time to UTC without any error and saves results.  Once it is saved it is no longer wrong.  AS I said time is always stored in UTC.

Comment: How do you convert an invalid DateTime to UTC? If you were working in Warsaw at 1:59AM on 29/3/20 and made a record of the time it would be valid so you could convert it to UTC (00:59). Two minutes later it would be 3:01AM in Warsaw which would also be valid so you could convert it to UTC (01:01). However, if you mistakenly created a TimeDate(2020, 3, 29, 2, 1, 0) to represent local time Warsaw it could not be converted to UTC as it's invalid.

Comment: Time isn't always stored in UTC, though I agree it's a good idea to do so. A DateTime object has no information about its timezone beyond its Kind property - essentially a flag to say whether it's UTC or not. Therefore you can create and store TimeDate(2020, 3, 29, 2, 1, 0) which would be valid in most timezones. However, it would not be valid if it related to local time in Warsaw. That's why I need something like timeZone.IsInvalidTime() - i.e. is the passed DateTime valid in this particular timezone?

Comment: Try it.  You will find I'm correct.  If you parse a string time to a DataTime.  Then change the timezone on the PC the date will also change.  The string DateTime is always valid as long a the properties are valid like minutes being between 0 to 60.  The Net library doesn't do a lot of checking with dates.  For example if you have a date12/15/20 and add one month you will get 1/15/21.

Comment: Regarding how can you convert an invalid local time to UTC, the last paragraph of [the remarks in `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime#remarks) cover that.  Basically it uses the standard time offset.  That isn't being employed in the implementation of `TimeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime`, but if it did it would have the same result.

Comment: @jdweng: No, constructing a `new DateTime(..., DateTImeKind.Local)` does *not* convert it into UTC. It doesn't perform any kind of time zone conversion on construction. See the .NET Core code at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/DateTime.cs#L206 and trace it through. `DateTime` maintains the values as presented (after *calendar* changes if necessary) and maintains a flag for the "kind". Note that *parsing* may perform conversions to or from UTC, but that's a different operation to construction.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, [the docs for `TimeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isinvalidtime#remarks) explain that returning `false` is the documented behavior when the `TimeZoneInfo` is not the local time zone, and is correct regardless of whether the time is valid in either the local time zone or the one belonging to the `TimeZoneInfo` object.  Indeed, [the implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0a2f0e6da98a784601b37d19417b930a33b2c478/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/TimeZoneInfo.cs#L502-L527) simply returns `false` in this case.

If you want to know if local times are valid or not, then you need to use the `TimeZoneInfo.Local` time zone, rather than one obtained by id.  It doesn't matter if that named time zone happens to be the local one or not, you need to be explicitly working with `TimeZoneInfo.Local` if you're testing `DateTimeKind.Local` values.

In other words, if your *computer's system local time zone* is indeed `"Central European Standard Time"` (assuming "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically" is turned on) then the following will return `True` as expected.

```
TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsInvalidTime(new DateTime(2020, 3, 29, 02, 01, 0, DateTimeKind.Local))
```

Comment: My problem is that I have no idea of the setting for the computer system's local timezone as my code is running on Azure so might get moved. What I want to do initialise TimeZoneInfo for whatever TimeZone the user has selected and then work out if the time he has given in a text box is valid. Seems a reasonable request!

Comment: If your code isn't running on a physical device (desktop, mobile, etc.) then you should not use `DateTimeKind.Local`.  In the scenario you just described, you should be using `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  If you parsed the string with `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`, or `Convert.ToDateTime`, it will *already* have `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` unless their is an offset in the string, in which case you'll get `DateTimeKind.Local`.  You can overcome that with `DateTime.SpecifyKind`.

Comment: Regarding Noda Time - If you can use it, then you should.  They key difference is that it will require you to think more carefully about these sorts of edge cases, where the built-in types will make assumptions.  They can both get the job done, but the assumptions can hurt. (Case in point: that the kind changes if there's an offset in the input string.)